# VPN ipsec tunnel from router to single windows server computer (gateway-to-host)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, ipsec

Firstly, is this possible?

The situation: 2 different ISP's. One has several servers and a firewall running. The other is limited to only one virtual server with one network card running windows server 2008r2.

I need to set up a site-to-site style VPN using IPsec between the firewall of one ISP and the windows host on the other (gateway-to-host). This host has to run a SQL-Server that I can access from the other ISP's servers through the VPN tunnel.

It seems looking at the RFC for IPsec that this should be possible using the features of Windows 2008, but I can't get it to work so far... It seems that I can't access any services running on the same computer or IP address used as the tunnel endpoint?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this if you are looking and decided to use OpenVPN instead, which does work for the given situation